# Need help for a html button on email

Tags: html

I have this button that redirects correctly on the browser; however, whenever I put it on my email in Gmail, it doesn't redirect

```html
<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">
    <A style="FONT-SIZE: 14px; 
              FONT-FAMILY: Arial; 
              WIDTH: 100%; 
              COLOR: #fff; 
              TEXT-ALIGN: center; 
              DISPLAY: inline-block; 
              LINE-HEIGHT: 50px; 
              BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0070ba; 
              border-radius: 50px" href="[websitelinkhere}">
        <STRONG>vérifiez votre compte </STRONG>
    </A>
</DIV>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be valid HTML; there are several mismatched tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try now. it need to be html verified.
check every time in: https://validator.w3.org

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <a style="font-size: 14px; 
              font-family: Arial; 
              width: 100%; 
              color: #fff; 
              text-align: center; 
              display: inline-block; 
              line-height: 50px; 
              background-color: #0070ba; 
              border-radius: 50px" href="[websitelinkhere]">
        <strong>vérifiez votre compte </strong>
    </a>
</div>
```